# Template and function pointer confuse

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I started learning c++ now. Im quite confuse about this definition. This is just a throwaway code as the actual implementation was on the book I was reading

```
class A
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void Hello(void(T::*func)())
    {
        func(); // Not working. Error term does not evaluate to function taking 0 argument
    }
};

class B
{
public:
     void funcA()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    }

    // This is called function pointers
    void funcB(void(*ptr)())
    {
        ptr();
    }
};

void main()
{
    A a;
    a.Hello(&B::funcA);


}
```

First is that what sort of template is that? If it's a template class shouldn't I delcare the **template** at the top of the **class A**?

Also why can't I call the func on `Hello()` like the same as calling a function pointer?

Comment: You're templating just the `Hello` function, with a signature that takes a function pointer. Then you bind B's `funcA` to A's `Hello`. I personally wouldn't use this approach. Which book is it? It seems a bit outdated and I worry it could teach you outdated concepts

Comment: @dau_sama I am reading a book titled SFML Game Development by Example. Is this style outdated? Because the book was just release I think a couple of months back.

Comment: func needs to be dereferenced, and also given an instance of T: (T().*func)(); http://cpp.sh/9sur

Comment: @stewbasic this is just a confusing code and its hard to read. Is there a way where I can just use the -> operator> like T()->func cause its not working for me

Comment: -> helps if you need to dereference the object, not the function; a->b() is equivalent to (*a).b(). If you are using C++11 or above, depending on what you are trying to do, you may get more readable code using std::function instead of function pointers.

Comment: @HoorahHoorah depending on taste and personal preferences yeah. A common pattern nowadays is to pass directly a functor, `void Hello(T&& Hander)` and either pass a lambda or a callable. It takes a while to get your head around it, and most people who say they're writing modern C++ still have old habits. Since you're starting I'd suggest to pick up what's called modern C++ from the start. 
This is a good starting point: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First is that what sort of template is that? If it's a template class shouldn't I delcare the template at the top of the class A?

`A::Hello` is [member function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template#Member_function_templates).

> Also why can't I call the func on Hello() like the same as calling a function pointer?

Because the parameter `func` of `Hello` is not a function pointer, but a member function pointer. You need an object to call on it. e.g.

```
template<class T>
void Hello(void(T::*func)())
{
    T t;
    (t.*func)();
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/NWDBK83962)</kbd>

Comment: Doesnt work as well. It says  func is not a member of B. Also the intellisense doesnt show the func when I press the Dot.

Comment: @HoorahHoorah It has nothing to do with templates, you should always do it.

Comment: @HoorahHoorah Did you try the link I posted? `(t.*func)();` and `(T().*func)();` both should work. What's the complete error message?

Comment: Yup tried it It works. Just a quick question is there a way to just use the -> operator? its also use for dereferencing right?

Comment: @HoorahHoorah `->` is used with pointer. e.g. `T* p = new T; (p->*func)(); delete p;` BTW you don't need pointer in this case at all.